# DevExpress DockPanel Width

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I can't change the size of this damn control not even god wanted me to! I've tried https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q458946, https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B96266 and https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B193170 without success...

My big probem here is that, if I SET "AutoSize", when a panel get hidden by "AutoHide", it WONT be visible again. If I disable "AutoSize" the panel shows up again, but its size will be off...

Any ideas? im really lost here... and I do belive that this is a bug...

Comment: If you are supposing this is a bug - maybe DevExpress support forum will be better place to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed it... the problem was the incapsulation regarding XtraTab regarding the docking of the inner UserControl that contains the other control of the dock, since DockManager needs a ContainerControl the function properly... note that IContainerControl from Control.GetContainerControl() is not enough...